# c++ Covariance issue with pointer return issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, constants, covariance

Since I had a lot of ambiguity in my post, I will redo it.
This is a problem I am encountering in a project which I am upgrading from a visual studio 6.0 environment to a visual studio 2012 environment.

I have a class which is derived from the followinh mfc class (CPropertyPage) which contains the following function. file is afxdlgs.h (mfc class)

```
class CPropertyPage : public CDialog
{
public:
virtual CPropertySheet *GetParentSheet();
}
```

I also still seem to have the problem after changing the forward declaration. Which was a result due to my bad formulation. So I have changed it back to it's original form.

The derived class looks like this.
header

```
class CBankDefImportSheet;
class CBankDefImportAssignPage : public CPropertyPage
{
protected:
    CBankDefImportSheet* GetParentSheet ();
}
```

in the cpp

```
#include "BankDefImportSheet.h"
CBankDefImportSheet* CBankDefImportAssignPage::GetParentSheet()
{
    return (CBankDefImportSheet *)GetParent ();
}
```

furthermore the CBangDefImportSheet is

```
class CBankDefImportSheet : public CPropertySheet
{}
```

when I compile I get the C2555 error that the return type differs and is not covariant from CPropertyPage::GetParentSheet.

I have tried adding the header of CBankDefImportSheet but that did not solve it. I have also read a possibility of being able to cast after the return type, but unsure if that would solve it, furthermore unsure of how to do it in this case.

EDIT: After solving, post below was part of the problem, however, so was const correctness. Shame on me!

in the header it should be specified as

```
 CBankDefImportSheet * GetParentSheet () const;
```

and furthermore in the cpp

```
 CBankDefImportSheet * CBankDefImportAssignPage::GetParentSheet() const
 {
     return ((CBankDefImportSheet *)GetParent ());
 }
```

Comment: This is confusing. I don't understand the relationship between `CPropertyPage`, `CPropertySheet`, `CDefImportSheet`, and `CDefImportSheetPage`. Can you show a minimal example that shows all the inheritance relationships?

Comment: Further to the above, is the full definition of `CDefImportSheet` available in the `CDefImportSheetPage` header, or just a forward declaration?

Comment: From memory, only fairly recent VC++ versions have supported covariant return types... which compiler version are you on?  You might want to do a quick search to see if that version supports this language feature....

Comment: vs 2012, the thing is it is a project i'm upgrading from vs 6.0.

Comment: @StevenBellens were you able to solve this?

Comment: yes i did actually. Though the answer came out of the left field, besides the problem stated below, it was a problem of const correctness, shame on me.

Comment: Ah good. You might want to mark an answer correct or put your own answer up. Looks like the missing 'const' was my issue too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question in the edit, but following advice i will also add it here. The main cause of my problem was that mfc dialog functions are const. Thus resulting in wrong covariance because of const correctness (or incorrectness in this case)

```
CBankDefImportSheet* GetParentSheet ();
```

in the header it should be specified as

```
CBankDefImportSheet * GetParentSheet () const;
```

and furthermore in the cpp

```
CBankDefImportSheet * CBankDefImportAssignPage::GetParentSheet() const
{
return ((CBankDefImportSheet *)GetParent ());
}
```

I'm glad this helped at least one other person already.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs to know at the point `CDefImportSheetPage::GetParentSheet()` is declared (where you've marked `.h`) that `CDefImportSheet` inherits from `CPropertySheet`.

It can't get that information from a simple forward declaration like:

```
class CDefImportSheet;
```

you'll need to include `CDefImportSheet`'s header there instead.

Comment: Was only part of the problem seems, const correctness was what the real breaker was.